# Obtener asistencia por usuario y el estado mensualmente con postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla en Postgres llamada ASISTENCIA que se ve así:

```
# USUARIO FECHA ESTADO
1 MARCO 2022-04-01 P
2 PABLO 2022-04-01 A
.
.
.
30 MARCO 2022-04-30 P
31 PABLO 2022-04-30 P
etc.


COLUMNA DE ESTADO
P = PRESENTE
A = AUSENCIA
```

¿Cómo escribo una consulta de tabulación cruzada que muestre el ESTADO por FECHA (DIARIO) del MES y si el usuario no registra la asistencia se genera automáticamente como las columnas y USUARIO como las filas?

El resultado de la consulta debería verse así:

```
                               ABRIL - 2022

USUARIO 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 … 30
----------------------------------------------------
MARCO P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P P … P

PAUL  A P P P P A P P P P P P A P P P P A P … P
```

Alguna idea? Estare muy agradecido

Comment: Creo que puedes utilizar la función crosstab(), chequea esta respuesta y puedes ajustar la solución para tu escenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo Gracias por la sugerencia.